# anchor not working inside offcanvas menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, navbar

i got a navbar which toggle in mobile resolution.
In standard desktop view the href="#section" is working on clicking an item li menu.
In mobile view, when the offcanvas container fades in the anchor didnt work anymore ! Is this a javascript problem ?

I guess the problem is that the canvas didnt fade out and close itself when clicking on anchor - the normal href to other subpages works.

Greetings

Tobias

Comment: Hi Tobias - I think we'll need more information to answer your question. Do you have a link to an example, some screenshots, or some sample code? Thanks!

Comment: After research - I saw this is a major problem in offcanvas menues. I try to solve it with a redirect.